# lambda for RDD query with if statement

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I'm creating an RDD which queries access logs. I want to extract all 404 errors (the logs are objects which can be queried. I'm using this code, but it seems I can't use pass in a lambda statement:

```
badRecords = (access_logs.map(lambda log: log if log.response_code == 404 else pass))
print 'Found %d 404 URLs' % badRecords.count()
```

What's the best/most efficient way of extracting a subset of logs based on the response_code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe filter will help?

```
badRecords = access_logs.filter(lambda log: log.response_code == 404)
```

I think the problem with the way you wrote it is:
When using map, you can't drop rows, every row is mapped to some other row. So there is no "pass" and the number of rows will not change.